# Handling Keil C51 keywords in the Eclipse indexer

Tags: c, eclipse, ide, c51

According to Keil C51, the following is valid:

```
static void kernel(void) small interrupt 1 using 2
{
    /* do stuff */
}
```

According to the Eclipse indexer, however, it isn't.
We can make the following definitions to help the case:

```
#define small /*small*/
#define interrupt /*interrupt*/
```

But unfortunately, we can't redefine the reserved keyword 'using' and it would be silly to redefine the numbers 1 or 2.

Is there a way to get the Eclipse indexer to parse ancient 8051 code in order to reap the benefits of a modern IDE?
Is there an alternative to Eclipse that can offer an efficient way to navigate through such a C project? Something with an equivalent "Open Call Hierarchy" function?

Comment: Are changes in the code an option? BTW, your defines don't do what you expect (they expand empty, because comments are removed before expansion), but that's not relevant for the effect here.

Answer (score 1):

In fact I created an Eclipse plugin exactly for this purpose a few years ago. I've uploaded the code to github. You may find a binary build of the plugin here:
https://github.com/andersesbensen/eclipse-c51-plugin/blob/master/deployment/eclipse-c51-plugin.zip

You need to activate to plugin under "Language Mappings" in your C project.

The plugin may not be perfect, but its a good start. Feel free to contribute to the code if you find anything not working.

Best regards 
Anders

Answer (score 0):

You *can* redefine the problematic keywords for the CDT indexer only. When the indexer is running, the symbol `__CDT_PARSER__` is defined. When compillation is running this symbol won't be defined. So you can do something like:

```
#ifdef __CDT_PARSER__
#undef small
#define small
//....etc
#endif
```

Or you can have a macro replacing the function definition:

```
#ifndef __CDT_PARSER__
#define KEIL_SPECIFIC_STUFF(param1, param2) small interrupt param1 using param2
#else 
#define KEIL_SPECIFIC_STUFF(param1, param2)
#endif
```

and then

```
static void kernel(void) KEIL_SPECIFIC_STUFF(1,2)
{
    /* do stuff */
}
```

Comment: The question is more related to the remaining part `1 using 2`. This is not that easy to get rid of.

Comment: I see.. Still it is possible to define a macro for the function definition that will expand to different thing based on this symbol. Let me update it.